# Pandas Dataframe from CSV creates wrong index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

im creating a dataframe using Pandas. Im saving it to csv with a chosen index (image 1).[image]
In a later step, im reading that csv-file again to recreate the dataframe. But for some reason I get new indices but I want to keep the old ones (image 2).[image]

Anyone knows how to fix that?

I used the standard functionality from Pandas

```
pd.read_csv(<path to csv file>)
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv(<path to csv file>, index_col=0)` ??

Comment: Wow that was easy, thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

You have to either don't save the index in the first place with`df.to_csv(index=False)`, or as @ScottC suggested, set the first column as your index when reading with `pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)`.